Area of a triangle in the complex plane is equal to?

Prove that in the complex plane, the area of a triangle with vertices $z_{1}, z_{2}, z_{3}$ is $$
\frac{1}{2}\left\vert z_{1} - z_{2}\right\vert^{2}\left\vert\,\Im\left(
\frac{z_{2} - z_{3}}{z_{2} - z_{1}}\right)\,\right\vert
$$
My attempt:


The area is equal to $\left\vert\,z_{2} - z_{1}\right\vert h/2$ where $h$ is the normal to the edge $z_{2} - z_{1}$.
From trigonometry, $\sin(\alpha) = h/\left\vert\,z_{2} - z_{3}\,\right\vert$ where
$\alpha$ is the angle between $z_{2} - z_{3}$ and $z_{2} - z_{1}$. Therefore, the area is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left\vert\,z_{2} - z_{1}\,\right\vert \left\vert\,z_{2} - z_{3}\,\right\vert \sin\left(\alpha\right)
$$
This is effectively where I got stuck.
I thought that somehow using the formulas for a complex number in trigonometric representation $r\left[\cos\left(\alpha\right) + {\rm i}\sin\left(\alpha\right)\right]$ should also help me somehow, but couldn't figure out how.
Why is
$$
\sin\left(\alpha\right) =
\Im\left(\frac{\frac{z_2-z_3}{|z_2-z_3|}}{\frac{z_2-z_1}{|z_2-z_1|}}\right)\ ?
$$

Thank you !.

Due to the fact that we have unit length complex numbers, we can set
$$\frac{z_2-z_3}{|z_2-z_3|}=e^{i \beta} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \frac{z_2-z_1}{|z_2-z_1|}=e^{i \gamma}$$
where $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are the polar angles (angles with respect to the horizontal axis) of the corresponding sides $[z_2,z_3]$ and $[z_2,z_1]$ .
You desire to understand why $$\sin \alpha = \Im(\frac{e^{i \beta}}{e^{i \gamma}})\tag{1}$$
Consider the RHS of (1). It can be written : $\Im(e^{i (\beta-\gamma)})=\sin(\beta-\gamma)$
giving the result because $\alpha = \beta-\gamma$.
Indeed the angle in vertex $z_2$ is the difference of polar angles of side $[z_2,z_3]$ and side $[z_2,z_1]$ .

Thank you for the detailed answer! It helped

Here are some things to think about.
$\frac 12 |z_1 - z_2|^2 \left|\Im \left(\frac {z_3-z_2}{z_1-z_2}\right)\right|$
$\frac 12|\Im [(z_3-z_2)(z_1-z_2)]|$
$\frac 12 |x_1y_2 - x_1y_3 + x_2y_3 - x_2y_1 + x_3y_1 - x_3y_2|$
Which is what you get from the shoe-laces algorithm.
$A = |a||b|\sin\theta$
$a = (z_1-z_2) = |z_1-z_2|(\cos \alpha + i\sin \alpha) = |z_1-z_2| e^{i\alpha}$
$b = (z_3-z_2) = |z_3-z_2|(\cos \beta + i\sin \beta) = |z_1-z_2| e^{i\beta}$
$\frac {b}{a} = \frac {|z_3-z_2|}{|z_1-z_2|} \frac {\cos \beta + i\sin \beta}{\cos \alpha + i\sin\alpha} = \frac {|z_3-z_2|}{|z_1-z_2|}(\cos \beta + i\sin \beta)(\cos \alpha - i\sin\alpha) \\= \frac {|z_3-z_2|}{|z_1-z_2|}(\cos (\beta - \alpha) + i\sin(\beta-\alpha)) = \frac {|z_3-z_2|}{|z_1-z_2|} e^{i(\beta - \alpha)}$

Thank you for the detailed answer! It helped
